# Fade out and unmount a loading screen component with React-spring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling with [react-spring](https://github.com/drcmda/react-spring) to fade out a loading screen and then unmount it.

The component unmounts but without animation and I can't figure why. I created a sandbox to illustrate:

https://codesandbox.io/s/nkxjxwo2xl

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Transition } from 'react-spring'

class Loader extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { loaded: false }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ loaded: true })
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const { percentage } = this.props
    const styles = {
      height: '100vh',
      width: '100vw',
      background: 'tomato'
    }
    return (
      <Transition native from={{ opacity: 1 }} leave={{ opacity: 0 }}>
        {!this.state.loaded &&
          (style => (
            <div style={Object.assign({}, styles, style)}>
              <div>{Math.round(percentage)} %</div>
            </div>
          ))}
      </Transition>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Loader percentage={0} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

There are no `react-spring` tags yet if anyone could create one, I think it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anyone finds this question.

Using the native attribute, you'll need to use `animated.div` (or any animated component) in order to have it animated. Or simply remove the native attribute. In my case, it is a loader which is not often displayed so I went for the easier way by simply removing the native attribute.

[More info on the Spectrum react-spring community](https://spectrum.chat/thread/d1cead01-16dd-4b22-b9d6-b08ad5281489)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you fixed it yourself, the animated.div component was missing. I would recommend the use of it, though. Even if your view is small, it will still be rendered out 60 times per second by React otherwise (meaning it will go through all component phases 60 times + render). With native set it renders once and the animation will be applied in a requestAnimationFrame-loop directly in the dom (via instance.style.setProperty, it completely skips React - which makes a difference once your app gets bigger.

Comment: I tested it the native way and the feeling about the animation is really improved on this basic example. So yeah, I switched to the native solution ! Thank you very much for your input btw.